# How to get the Android app's root view from React Native?

Tags: android, view, react-native

Trying to write a react-native native adapter for the [Flipboard bottomsheet component](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet/).

I can instantiate their `BottomSheetLayout` just fine, but having trouble trying to set it up with views.

Per [API docs](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet/wiki/API-Documentation) I'm trying to call `setContentView` with the "view which is shown under the sheet being presented, usually the root view of your application", but I can't seem to get the right view from my React class.

Tried saving a reference to the `ReactRootView` instantiated in `MainActivity`, but it's rejected with "The specified child already has a parent".

Is there another root view to React Native apps I'm missing? How can I get a reference to it from my adapter class?

My component manager class, simplified:

```
public class ReactBottomSheetManager extends ViewGroupManager<ReactBottomSheetLayout> {
  private View mRootView = null;
  private View mContentView = null;

  public static final int COMMAND_OPEN = 1;

  public ReactBottomSheetManager(View rootView) {
    super();
    mRootView = rootView; // this is the ReactRootView from MainActivity
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "BottomSheetAndroid";
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactBottomSheetLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
    ReactBottomSheetLayout view = new ReactBottomSheetLayout(context);
    view.setPeekOnDismiss(true);
    view.setContentView(mRootView);  // here is where things blow up
    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
    return MapBuilder.of("open", COMMAND_OPEN);
  }

  @Override
  public void receiveCommand(ReactBottomSheetLayout view, int commandType, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
    switch(commandType) {
      case COMMAND_OPEN: {
        view.showWithSheetView(mContentView);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  // overriding addView to save a reference to the view instead of adding it
  // to the bottom sheet layout right away. we'll add/show this view when
  // it's time to open the sheet.
  @Override
  public void addView(ReactBottomSheetLayout parent, View child, int index) {
    Log.d("ReactNative", "addView called with index=" + index);
    mContentView = child;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean needsCustomLayoutForChildren() {
    // BottomSheetLayout will lay out it's own children
    return true;
  }
}
```

`ReactBottomSheetLayout` is a very simple class inheriting Flipboard's `BottomSheetLayout`.

Thanks!